# Handling Sessions using selenium

Tags: java, session, selenium

I am new to selenium, and using web-driver, i have problem that if i test manually by clicking   on particular button called "Add Device" (after Login) it works fine, if i test using selenium web-driver script(java) it gives session time-out. To fix this what i need to learn and do.
How to handle Session management. What tried so far is :(ofcourse you may not need this code)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("ppppppppp");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'loginDiv1']/form/a")).click();
        str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'container']/nav/ul/li[6]/a")).getText();
        System.out.println(str);
        assertEquals(str,"xxxxxx@gmail.com   Log Out");
driver.findElement(By.linktext("Add Device")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'fancybox-skin']/a")).click();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have rights check server log for any exception thrown during test execution time.

Comment: where can i find server log.

Comment: In the machine where your server is running.

Comment: It says   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: nuemerads not bound